# In sugarcrm 6.5 while installing new custom module , the below error is thrown - mode of operation not specified

Tags: module, sugarcrm

Below steps I have performed:

1) Uploaded new module through Module Loader

2) Clicked on install the uploaded module

3) On clicking agree and click next receiving an error - mode of
operation not specified

Comment: You need to check compatibility of crm. Open manifiest.php file and check the version of crm is mention in it or not.

Comment: Where can i find manifest.php?

Comment: just extract the zip file of you new module. You will find that file in root folder.

Comment: ya i got that file and i checked the version..

Comment: Version is mentioned

Comment: Its not the problem with version.We are not able to install and uninstall any  module.We have created couple of  custom modules and we have made some changes also.Now whenever we are trying to install any module it shows above error.

Comment: See.. I cant figure out exact cause of this error. You need to check the permissions as well where you are trying to add the files,folders in crm. Aslo check the file paths are correct or not, check slashes, syntax errors etc

Comment: Checked permission.Still  same Error.